# Realizar plantilla para obtener información del IFE/INE (OCR)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, ocr

Estoy intentando obtener la información de una credencial del *IFE/INE*. He realizado pruebas con la *API* de *Google Mobile Vision* (https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview)
para poder lograrlo pero me obtiene muy pocos campos u obtiene la información muy poco entendible.

Cabe destacar que la información de la credencial la obtiene de forma secuencial, pero en ocasiones no lo hace. Realmente no tengo idea de por qué a veces sea así y a veces no.

He descargado unos *OCRs* comerciales y veo que utilizan ***Tesseract***, y me gustaría hacer una plantilla pero la verdad no tengo mucha idea de cómo realizarla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ACTUALIZACIÓN: Te dejó el link con la biblioteca que hice, espero te sirva aún. https://github.com/BrandonVargas/AndroidOCRFforID

Acabo de realizar uno, lamentablemente no puedo hacerlo publico, pero puedo guiarte un poco. Estoy utilizando Mobile Vision como mencionas, antes use Tesseract el cual es muy bueno pero aumenta demasiado el tamaño de tu aplicación. Para empezar debes saber que existen 5 tipos de IFE/INE A, B, C, D y E de las cuales la única que no esta vigente es la tipo A. Ahora bien para que se haga una correcta lectura de los campos lo primero que debes hacer es recortar la foto al tamaño de la IFE/INE para que quede como la imagen que muestras, una vez hecho esto lo siguiente es sacar medidas, como hacerlo? Tomemos como referencia la imagen que pusiste. Supongamos que requerimos sacar el nombre, y que la imagen mide 5.4 de alto por 8.6 de ancho. Sabemos que android toma el origen de una imagen en la esquina superior izquierda, tomamos las medidas a partir de ahí, el nombre empieza en 0.3 cm en X y 1.6 cm en Y, tiene una anchura promedio de 4 cm y una altura de 1 cm. Una vez teniendo esas medidas como base se sacan los "porcentajes" y quedaría con  X = (0.3/8.6), Y = (1.6/5.4), ANCHO = (4/8.6) y ALTO = (1/5.4). Teniendo estos datos podemos crear un bitmap del nombre a partir del recortado anteriormente y pasarlo a la API. Es importante sacar estos datos "proporcionales" ya que en Android existe una gran variedad de cámaras y las fotos son de diversos tamaños. Cuando pueda publicar la biblioteca que hice editare esto. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta amigo. Como sabes a partir de que punto recortar la imagen, ¿Tienes algún cuadro de apoyo para que el usuario coloque su credencial?

Comment: Claro, pongo un marco de referencia en el centro de la pantalla, asi puedo tomar como referencia el centro del bitmap y calcular el punto de inicio del bitmap recortado int xi =(int)((bitmap.getWidth()/2)-(bitmap.getWidth()*0.1092)); int yi =(int)((bitmap.getHeight()/2)-(bitmap.getHeight()*0.375)); bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,xc,yc,(int)(bitmap.getWidth()*0.74), (int)(bitmap.getHeight()*0.39)); Los números por los que se multiplican son los porcentajes que normalmente ocupa la ife/ine en una foto con un relacion de aspecto 4/3

Comment: el marco lo defino asi:<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rl_ife_view_front"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_below="@+id/view_top"
android:visibility="gone">
   <View
       android:id="@+id/ife_view_front"
       app:layout_widthPercent="90%"
       app:layout_aspectRatio="160%"
       android:layout_margin="2dp"
       android:background="@drawable/ife_shape_front"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"/></android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo

Comment: Esto es muy interesante seguiré intentandolo, gracias. No se si pueda seguir haciendote preguntas de las dudas que vayan saliendo.

Comment: Perdón no había visto esto en un tiempo, claro pregunta

Comment: Gracias. Lo deje por un rato, actualmente lo retome y estoy intentando recortar la imagen del margen de referencia o de apoyo.
Estoy obteniendo la posición de mi ImageView ( Contiene el marco de referencia) con el getLocationOnScreen() y desde el onPictureTaken convierto del formato NV21 a bitmap con YuvImage y el tamaño que obtengo del camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().
Posteriormente estoy recortando el bitmap original con las posiciones del ImageView Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, x, size.height- y, width, height).

Comment: Hice la prueba en un teléfono S5 y el recorte lo hace correctamente, pero al hacer la prueba del recorte en un MOTO G1, la imagen del IFE sale a la mitad, no se si sea problema de la densidad de la pantalla lo que este ocasionando esto. ¿Como crear el soporte para las diferentes densidades? ¿O que crees que estoy haciendo mal?. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola, creo que tu problema radica en el el tamaño con que se toman las fotos, como te mencione anteriormente es importante que la foto tomada tenga una relación de aspecto 4/3, aquí surge un problema con los celulares Samsung ya que debido a su capa de personalización no te deja editar los parámetros de la cámara, así que queda hacer pruebas para determinar los tamaños, por otra parte a finales de este mes subiré mi código a github, tal vez te sirva mejor como referencia. :D

Comment: Si yo creo que debe ser eso, seguiré haciendo pruebas, esperaré ansiosamente para aprender, gracias por compartir tus conocimientos.